# Unable to Marshall a Drools KnowledgeSession

Tags: java, marshalling, drools

I have used the code available in the following link see if i can Marshall and Unmarshall a Drools session.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=droolsjbpm-master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/integrationtests/SerializationHelper.java

Used the method getSerialisedStatefulKnowledgeSession.

I am getting the following error at the first line of the method.

**Line of code:**

```
Marshaller marshaller = MarshallerFactory.newMarshaller(ksession.getKnowledgeBase(),(ObjectMarshallingStrategy[])ksession.getEnvironment().get(EnvironmentName.OBJECT_MARSHALLING_STRATEGIES));
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Lorg.kie.api.marshalling.ObjectMarshallingStrategy; cannot be cast to
>   [Lorg.drools.marshalling.ObjectMarshallingStrategy;   at
>   com.sample.SessionMarshall.getSerialisedStatefulKnowledgeSession(SessionMarshall.java:105)
>     at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:36)

Can someone please suggest me how can i resolve these errors.
Or can someone provide me code snippet to Marshall a drools session.

Answer (score 0):

I have used drools jars version of 6.2+

Once i changed my drools jars to version 5.4.0 and related jar versions as shown below, the issue has been resolved.

drools-compiler-5.4.0.Final,
drools-core-5.4.0.Final,
knowledge-api-5.4.0.Final,
knowledge-internal-api-5.4.0.Final

mvel2-2.1.0.drools16,
protobuf-java-2.4.1,
antlr-runtime-3.3